# How to send the same message multiple times?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Sorry for the lack of information, I promise to read the posting rules.

The script is based to send messages in whatsapp groups.

The script opens the browser on the whatsapp web page and then I read the QR CODE, for the script to trigger the messages.

The problem is that it sends a message only once to the list of groups, I need it to send a message per hour to each group, without opening the browser, because if this is done, I will need to read the QR CODE again and that cannot happen.

Version Selenium 4.0

Complete code, it is without errors, I would just like to implement the retry action without opening the browser again.

[Comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfXUX.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter 
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions, Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

opts = ChromeOptions()
opts.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
opts.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
servico=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=servico, options=opts)

driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
driver.implicitly_wait(60) # seconds

col_nome = 'Nome'
col_mensagem = 'Mensagem'

infor_excel = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\felip\\OneDrive\\Área de 
Trabalho\\Web\\Mensagens.xlsx')
lista_msg_excel = (infor_excel[[col_nome,col_mensagem]])


def buscar_contato(contato):
campo_pesquisa = driver.find_element(By. CSS_SELECTOR,'.selectable- 
text')
sleep(2)
campo_pesquisa.click()
sleep(2)
campo_pesquisa.send_keys(str(row['Nome']))
sleep(2)
campo_pesquisa.send_keys(Keys. ENTER)
def enviar_mensagem(mensagem):
campo_mensagem = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
'p[class="selectable-text copyable-text"]')
sleep(2)
campo_mensagem[0].click()
sleep(2)
campo_mensagem[0].send_keys(str(row['Mensagem']))
sleep(2)
campo_mensagem[0].send_keys(Keys. ENTER)

for index, row in lista_msg_excel.iterrows():
buscar_contato(col_nome) 
enviar_mensagem(col_mensagem)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: what is the problem? Do you get error or what? We can't run it, and we can't read in your mind. You have to describe all details in question (not in comments)

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: `get()` opens browser only once. I don't understand why you don't want to use it again. Besides, if after sending first message it doesn't show page for next mesasge then  you may have to `get()` the same page again and you have to find element again.

Comment: This problem seems to have nothing to do with vscode. I deleted the tag for you.

Comment: changes have been made to the original text, thank you all

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem, inserting several for, as below:

```
for index, row in lista_msg_excel.iterrows():
  buscar_contato(col_nome) 
  enviar_mensagem(col_mensagem)

sleep(1800)

for index, row in lista_msg_excel.iterrows():
   buscar_contato(col_nome) 
   enviar_mensagem(col_mensagem)

sleep(1800)

for index, row in lista_msg_excel.iterrows():
   buscar_contato(col_nome) 
   enviar_mensagem(col_mensagem)

sleep(1800)

for index, row in lista_msg_excel.iterrows():
   buscar_contato(col_nome) 
   enviar_mensagem(col_mensagem)
```